# Using a query string with an form in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 view with a form and i want to pass in a parameter via query string. Heres my form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", new { db = @Request.QueryString["db"] }, FormMethod.Post))
```

Heres my Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model,string db)
```

When I click my Login button, and step through the code, the param db is null. Im passing it in like this:

```
  http://localhost:64632/?db=someValue
```

My route looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{db}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", db = UrlParameter.Optional           } // Parameter defaults
);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why can't you just put `db` as a property in your Model, set it on load of that page (it must be set in the query string somewhere), then put it in a hidden field, that way when you submit the form you have the value. Default MVC model binding FTW :)

Comment: This is a business requirement. The current app accepts db as a query string parameter and the client doesnt want to change that

Comment: I was wondering if we could use `@Request.QueryString["db"]` in the view. Did you check whether that value was set correctly?

Comment: Hmmm.... interesting; however for me I am not able to recreate the issue. Your code works 100% fine. BTW what about your model; does it have values?

Comment: Yes my model has values (username password etc)

Answer (score 1):

Your route is expecting `db` to be a token in the url:

```
http://localhost:64632/Account/LogOn/someValue
```

You could grab the value from the querystring in your controller and store the db parameter in a `ViewBag` and it will be available on your form.

Comment: I wish i could, but this is a business requirement. Plus i thought with MVC, a query string is the same as what you described

Answer (score 1):

If that's the only route you have, then presumably the page you're currently on looks like "/controller/action/dbValue". In this case,

```
@Request.QueryString["db"]
```

won't fetch anything because db is a route value, it's not part of the query string. You could use

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["db"]
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

It works. I am doing the same thing. I can retrieve the query string values on a http post: `Request["queryparametername"]`

Answer (score 0):

well, this is a get method link : "http://localhost:64632/?db=someValue"

and you used the HttpPost attribute.

Comment: Methods using the HttpPost attribute can still receive parameters from a query string.